# Logic for tagging like WhatsApp in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to make chatting App in Objective-C.

In this I  want to implement tagging like WhatsApp.

When the user enters a @ in the group it should show the list of the group members. 
I try to do but sometimes facing issue when entering backspace after for example  "@xyz". I am not getting output as expected.

Can you show me some example or a  tutorial which I can take as  reference.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please first have a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Simply,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    textViews.delegate = self;
    namesArray = @[@"John",@"Mathew”,@“iOS”];
    membersTable.hidden = true;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView { // Delegate method called when any text is modified

    if ([textViews.text isEqualToString: @""]) {

        membersTable.hidden = true;
    }else{

        if ([[textView.text substringFromIndex: [textView.text length] - 1] isEqualToString:@"@"]) {
            NSLog(@"Success");
            membersTable.hidden = false;
        }else{
            membersTable.hidden = true;
        }
    }

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return namesArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [membersTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text =[namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Members tableView will show when user entered "@" symbol in your textView then user can choose members by selecting tableView